# Custom POST with json-server, request.body === undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, json-server

I am using https://github.com/typicode/json-server to mock data for a project.

I have set up the server according to the documentation, but when creating a custom POST request, using curl:

```bash
curl 'http://localhost:4200/api/stamoplysninger/beregningsvaerdier/' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Origin: http://localhost:4200' \
  -H 'Referer: http://localhost:4200/' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5060.134 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="103", ".Not/A)Brand";v="99"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"' \
  --data-raw '{"virkningsaar":2025,"workzonenummer":"12-1234567",
"msbOevrigeEjendommeProcent":81.2,"msbAlmeneBoligerProcent":0,
"afsavnsrentesatsProcent":12.99,"forsigtighedsprincipProcent":100,
"grundskyldMaxVaerdiPromille":669,"grundskyldMinVaerdiPromille":48,
"grundskyldMaxVaerdiProduktionsjordPromille":551.27,
"grundskyldMinVaerdiProduktionsjordPromille":4,
"daekningsafgiftMaxOffentligPromille":373,
"daekningsafgiftMaxErhvervPromille":639}' \
  --compressed
```

I cannot read the body of the request:

```js
server.post('/api/stamoplysninger/beregningsvaerdier/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body) // logs 'undefined'
})
```

I have also explicitly set

```js
server.use(jsonServer.bodyParser);
```

Json-server is otherwise set as per default.

Comment: Is your body actually JSON with the correct MIME type specified?

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] (which should include details of the request).

Comment: You have not set any `body` values in your `server.post(...)` snippet. `req`: request. `res`: response. Don't you want to check the response?

Comment: The req is the incomming request, and I presume I have to look for the body here right?

Comment: I'm missing `-X POST` in your `curl` command. Are you actually doing a POST request?

Comment: Yes, doing POST, the request is received at the json-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the code you provided the error is not immediately reproducible. But I was able to create a situation where the problem can occur. But I am not sure if that's the exact issue you are facing.

It can happen if you apply the body-parser AFTER you define your route.

E.g.
This does not work

```
server.post('/test/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  //Undefined
})
server.use(jsonServer.bodyParser)
```

This does:

```
server.use(jsonServer.bodyParser)
server.post('/test/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  //The Json Body
})
```

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the problem, thanks for the answer, i dont have enough rep to upvote :).
I thought 'const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults();' used bodyParser as default ...